# Can you purchase magic items not in your chronicle sheets or always available in PFS?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society, organized-play

According to the Pathfinder Society Roleplaying Guild Guide (v8.0). A Pathfinder Society character may purchase any items in their chronicle sheets plus any items in the "Always Available Items" list on page 20. It also says on page 20 that characters may purchase items by capitalizing on their fame and there a "Maximum item cost per fame" table. However, I don't see anything in the prestige awards that you can use to buy expensive items except for the 750GP "free" ones.

Does your Fame score allow you to buy ANY ITEM that is within the limits of the table, even if it's not in a chronicle sheet or the Always Available list?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

As the Guild Guide says, on p20, under the Always Available items

> Beyond the gear noted above, your character is
>   restricted to purchasing additional items either from his
>   accumulated Chronicle sheets or by capitalizing on his
>   Fame (see page 21).

And, under Benefits of Fame on p21

> A character’s Fame score determines the maximum gp value of any items she can purchase from the Pathfinder Society or her faction, as detailed in the table on page 19. The character must still actually spend the gold to receive the desired item.

So, as an example, a character with no additional items on her chronicle sheets would need a minimum Fame score of 9 to be able to purchase a potion of Fly. The ubiquitous Wand of Cure Light Wounds would also require a Fame score of 9, in the absence of a chronicle sheet item.

Comment: This seems to make sense. But then I've seen Chronicle Sheets that have "Potion of Cure Moderate Wounds" as a tier 4-6 reward. That seems totally pointless then.

Comment: Yes, it is, but the writers seem to like to be complete...the more useful things on Chronicles are generally the wands with lower numbers of charges, or items with higher than normal caster levels, which you can't normally purchase at all.